# Can I turn off eslint tyfedef rule for destructuring in lambdas

Tags: typescript, eslint, destructuring, typescript-eslint

I am wondering is it possible to turn off typedef rule only for array or object destructuring in lambdas ?

```js
getPersonsNames(): string[] {
    type Person = { name: string; age: number };
    const persons: Person[] = [
        { name: `Jan Kowalski`, age: 12 },
        { name: `Justyna Kowalczyk`, age: 22 }
    ];
    return persons.map(({ name }) => name); // ESLint: Expected a type annotation.(@typescript-eslint/typedef)
}
```

In general, I want to use typedfees for destructuring but in those kinds of cases I do not want to. Is there a way to exclude those cases ?

---

I tried to add `'arrow-parameter': false,` (and `arrowParameter: false` as you can see above) to `@typescript-eslint/typedef` but it didn't help at all.

> Documentation of this rule which I used: **[@typescript-eslint/typedef](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/typedef.md#requires-type-annotations-to-exist-typedef)**

**Files to reproduce**

**`.eslintrc.js`** config file:

```js
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        createDefaultProgram: true,
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    ],
    rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/typedef': [
            'error',
            {
                'arrowParameter': false,
                'propertyDeclaration': true,
                'parameter': true,
                'memberVariableDeclaration': true,
                'callSignature': true,
                'variableDeclaration': true,
                'arrayDestructuring': true,
                'objectDestructuring': true
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

**`.gitignore`**:

```
node_modules
```

**`index.ts`**:

```typescript
function getPersonsNames(): string[] {
    type Person = { name: string; age: number };
    const persons: Person[] = [
        { name: `Jan Kowalski`, age: 12 },
        { name: `Justyna Kowalczyk`, age: 22 }
    ];
    return persons.map(({ name }) => name); // ESLint: Expected a type annotation.(@typescript-eslint/typedef)
}

getPersonsNames();
```

**`package.json`**:

```json
{
  "name": "typedef-in-destructuring-lambdas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

**`tsconfig.json`**:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6",
            "es2019"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to force the use of unnecessary type annotations?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is the requirement in this project and team workflow :/

Comment: That's unfortunate. :-)

Comment: unfortunately yep :')

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I created  repository with minimal code needed to reproduce

Comment: I've copied the contents of those files into the question. The whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** the question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule does not support this - it treats all destructuring as the same.
Note that more customisability won't be added to the rule because it shouldn't be used in most codebases.

Using it, and adding unnecessary type annotations is an anti-pattern, and has a negative effect on your codebase.

---

This rule isn't really intended to be used day-to-day in a codebase, it's intended to help you migrate your codebase so you can turn on the `noImplicitAny` compiler option.

Unnecessary type annotations everywhere is bad for your codebase. Each one incurs a maintenance cost (you have to manually update them to keep them in sync), and each one also *slows down compilation*, because TypeScript has to take time to validate that the annotation is correct.

As the maintainer of `@typescript-eslint`, I ***strongly*** advise *against* using the `typedef` rule.

Comment: Very well said. Additionally, unnecessary type annotations can act as hidden type assertions (i.e. `let xs: any[] = [{}]; xs.map((x: string) => x.toUpperCase()) // terrible!`)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that will impact compile process (nice catch). Very good answer. Thank you mate